# Open Storage Management programatically

Tags: storage, automation

In macOS Sierra there’s a new [Storage Management](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996) option. One way to get to it is via `/Applications/Utilities/System Information.app` (then with the app open) `Window` → `Storage Management`.

I’d like to accomplish all that programatically, including closing the `System Information.app` window.

If there’s a solution it’ll likely involve AppleScript or JXA, but I’m not picky on the method.

Comment: @LangLangC I don’t want to just see the information. I want to actually manage storage. I’m not looking for something *like* the `Storage Management` window; I’m looking for it exactly, without extra cruft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inadvertently found the solution. `Storage Management` exists as a standalone app after all, but not where one would expect. Seeing as the question has upvotes, meaning other people might be looking for it as well, I’m answering it instead of deleting it. You can find the app in:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Storage Management.app
```